# Query single entry from ELKs Elasticsearch via HTTP

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm trying to build some kind of monitor for my ELK stack. I want to know when/if my ELK is down. This will be just a simple solution. I was tasked with integrating a on/off signal within a bigger, global monitoring tool.

So I want to query my ELKs elasticsearch for the latest entry that matches one particular field value. My ELK data contains a field for each `access.log` row that states which server was the origin. So there is always say `server_node.raw=Tomcat1` oder `Tomcat2` or ...

I do get a result from my index but this seems like metadata to me. `http://10.170.121.148:9100/logstash-2015.11.10/?pretty`

Is there a way to query ES for the latest entry that matches `server_node.raw=Tomcat1` using a simple HTTP request?

Using `server_node.raw` in Kibana works perfectly fine.

Anyone with an idea? I'd appreciate it.
Thanks in advance and regards. Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right path, you can simply query your logstash index with a [URI search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html) and `&q=server_node.raw:...` like this

```
curl -XGET 'http://10.170.121.148:9100/logstash-2015.11.10/_search?q=server_node.raw:Tomcat1&pretty'
```

Comment: Worked perfectly fine. Only dynamic parts are index-timestamp (per default elasticsearch rotates every night) and server_node. This one got me everything I wanted. ```http://10.170.121.148:9100/logstash-YYYY.MM.DD/_search?pretty&q=server_node.raw:SERVER_NODE&fields=@timestamp&sort=@timestamp:desc&size=1```